# Capture the value of attribute in string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have file content as String in java. I need to capture the  value of  attribute code i.e.  `key.test.text` and `key.test.text1`

```
 <input type="button" value="<s:message code="key.test.text"  />"
 <input type="button2" value='<s:message code="key.test.text1'  />"
```

There can be spaces before `=` like `<input type="button" value = "<s:message code="key.test.text"  />"`

I am not sure how to capture it with regex or string ?

Comment: Use an XML parser. Don't use a regex on XML. If the above is all your input, you may get away with a regex, but it'll get ugly quickly with more input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
String regex = "value\\s*=\\s*[\"']<s:message\\s+code\\s*=\\s*[\"']([^\"']+)[\"']\\s*\\/>";
```

Capture group #1 will return a desired string for each match.

---

Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String input = "...";
String regex = "value\\s*=\\s*[\"']<s:message\\s+code\\s*=\\s*[\"']([^\"']+)[\"']\\s*\\/>";

List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
  allMatches.add(m.group(1));
}

System.out.println(allMatches);
```

Test this demo code [**here**](https://ideone.com/kdPnj3).

Comment: Its not matching for input `<s:message code="label.eligibility.home.heading" text="some text" />`

Comment: @user3198603 - Change `\\s*` at the end or the regex pattern to `.*?`. https://ideone.com/o7mcBa

Comment: Also can you please explain `([^\"']+)` part ? I understand `()` is for capturing group but did not get inside part . I tried `"<s:message\\s*code\\s*=\\s*[\"'](.*)[\"']\\s*[abc]*\\s*\\/>")` to capture anything that come b/w `'` or `"` but only returns 1 result ?

Comment: @user3198603 - `[^\"']+` means one or more of characters other than `'` or `"`. In regards to your regex pattern, try to change your greedy `(.*)` to a non-greedy `(.*?)` and test it again.

Comment: For input
`<s:message code="label" text="someText"/>` its returning `label" text="someText` but i need just `label` ?

Comment: @user3198603 - Are you sure you used my pattern from my first comment above? I assume you forgot to use `?` behind `*` and used `.*` instead of `.*?`

Comment: BTW - the pattern `[\"']([^\"']+)[\"']` will capture to group #1 anything between single and/or double quotes (`"` and/or `'`)

Answer (score -1):

You need just need to json_encode the string and then assign you button value and then you can read it.

Here is another solution.

First use [StringEscapeUtils#unescapeHtml4()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) (or [#unescapeXml()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml(java.lang.String)), depending on the original format) to unescape. Then use [String#replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to get rid of characters which are creating issue.You can take help from [printable ASCII range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

Then send it to the button value.

Answer (score -1):

Per your latest need per your post and comments below accepted answer

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(
            "<s:message.*?code.*?=.*?[\"'](.*?)[\"'].*?>")
            .matcher(content);

    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

        ++count;
    }
```

Comment: The performance of your pattern is horrible. You are using lazy (non-greedy) quantifiers `.*?` where you can use greedy ones that would work instantly. Other words, if you can, use greedy quantifiers (e.g. `\\s*` or `[^\"']*`), so the matching will take a small fraction of the time in compare to your current approach.